# How do I check if an integer exists in a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

for example

```
cout<<"What number"<<endl;
cin>>number;
```

This would give me

```
What number
123
```

So how would I check if 1 or 12 or 32 was in the input number?

Comment: Read a string and search for "1", "12", ...

Comment: or convert the number to a string and search it

Comment: @Sam In fact condition either the number contains 1 or 12 is equivalent to the condition whether the number contains 1.:)

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can take the input in the form of a string and check if the required numbers are present.

```
string input;
cout << "What number?" << endl;
cin >> input;
string to_find = "12";
int location = input.find(to_find);
if (location == -1)
  cout << "12 wasn't found in the string" << endl;
else
  cout << "12 was present in the string, beginning at index " << location << endl;
// You can similarly do this for other cases.
```

Things you should take care of is to check whether the input was actually a number. Also, if you want to check many numbers, you can store all of them in an array, and put the `find()` command inside a loop.

Comment: I would prefer pre-initialized values, just in case

Comment: @therainmaker  Ingenious! And what about a number like, for example, 10?:)

Comment: @therainmaker Your code is entirely wrong because you have not understood the assignment.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Thanks for pointing it out. I had not understood the question initially. Stupid error on my part. Is it fine now?

Comment: @therainmaker I would not say that it is fine but at least it is closer to the task description.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What is the reason for not being fine? Is it because I have not given a complete code, and left some of it to the OP. Or is it because my code isn't as modular as yours (although I do mention it later in my answer). Or is there some other reason? I would appreciate feedback as it would help me get better, and that is why I'm here. :)

Comment: @therainmaker For example it is  a bad idea to use -1 instead of std::string::npos.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow : Thanks for that. Any reason though? Or is it readability?

Comment: @therainmaker It is simply confusing code. And in general it is a bad idea to use magic numbers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Thanks. Will incorporate this in my future answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard function `std::to_string` to convert the number to a string and then apply method `find`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int number = 123;

    for ( int x : { 1, 12, 32 } )
    {
        if ( std::to_string( number ).find( std::to_string( x ) ) != std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cout << "Number " << number << " contains " << x << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Number " << number << " does not contain " << x << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Number 123 contains 1
Number 123 contains 12
Number 123 does not contain 32
```

I suppose that searched numbers are also entered as integers. Otherwise you could have an array of string literals that correspond to the numbers.

Also from your description it is not clear whether number 123 contains for example 13 or 32 or 21.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of occurrence of each digits in input number and then check it with the pattern numbers digit.
If patterns digit is less than input numbers count - the answer is no otherwise yes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just convert the number to a string and check that against your numbers.

```
int number;
std::cin >> number;
if ( std::to_string( number ).find( "1" ) != std::string::npos )
    std::cout << "The number contains 1" << std::endl;
if ( std::to_string( number ).find( "12" ) != std::string::npos )
    std::cout << "The number contains 12" << std::endl;
if ( std::to_string( number ).find( "32" ) != std::string::npos )
    std::cout << "The number contains 32" << std::endl;
```